# Georgia font lookalike

Tags: fonts

Is there a free lookalike font for the [Microsoft's Georgia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_%28typeface%29) font that I could use with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: If you own Georgia, you can use it with those engines.

Comment: @egreg: I do not own a copy of Windows OS.

Comment: http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CharisSILfont and for demo http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Charis-SIL

Comment: http://fontsimilar.com/to/georgia/#comments? (No idea if this is accurate though. But there is surprisingly little turned up by a web search for a georgia look-alike.)

Comment: Georgia is my favourite font for text when I'm on Windows. I particularly like the drop numbers. On LaTeX I use Palatino with the osf option, [osf]{mathpazo}. It works especially well in print.

Comment: Charter was designed by the same person as Georgia and shares many of its features. Linux Libertine is kind of in the same neighborhood.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not TeX related: it's a general font question.

Comment: If you dual-boot Windows, you can also put symbolic links to the updated versions in your Windows font directory in either `/usr/local/share/fonts` or `~/.fonts`.

Comment: Georgia is one of Microsoft’s Core fonts, so an old version of it is free-as-in-beer. Search your package repo. On Ubuntu, it’s `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. You can `fc-match Georgia` to test whether you have the font installed already.